# UICollectionView duplicating cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have created a UICollectionView programmatically like below

```
 UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
_collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-200) collectionViewLayout:layout];
[_collectionView setDataSource:self];
[_collectionView setDelegate:self];

[_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
[_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[vc.view addSubview:_collectionView];
```

And when I tried to add images into the cell then I can see duplicated contents. Here are my delegate methods:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [documentImageArray count];
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cells = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cells==nil){
        cells=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    UIImageView *pic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cells.frame];
    pic.image=[documentImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];


    [cells addSubview:pic];
    return cells;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
        return CGSizeMake(155, 155.f);

    } else if(IS_IPHONE_6) {
        return CGSizeMake(182.5, 182.5); //Max size

    } else if (IS_IPHONE_6P) {
        return CGSizeMake(175, 175.f);

    } else {
        return CGSizeMake(140, 140.f);  
    }        
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```

This is what am getting as result:

[image]

Comment: Better build UI in your prototype cell and re-use it. Don't init new and addSubview in dequeue.Don't need to check when cell=nil like in talbleView.

Comment: @LESANG, he has registered the prototype cell and he reuses it already; but I agree with you about the `cell == nil` is totally unnecessary condition in the code as it does exactly the same as the line above (probably the OP does not know how prototype cell works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [documentImageArray count];
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cells=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cells==nil){
        cells=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    for (UIView *view in cells.contentView.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
    UIImageView *pic =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cells.frame];
    pic.image=[documentImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];


    [cells addSubview:pic];
    return cells;
}
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(IS_IPHONE_5){
        return CGSizeMake(155, 155.f);

    }else if(IS_IPHONE_6){
        return CGSizeMake(182.5, 182.5); //Max size

    }else if (IS_IPHONE_6P){
        return CGSizeMake(175, 175.f);

    }else{
        return CGSizeMake(140, 140.f);

    }

}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    }
```

Comment: whats thisi self.contentview ??

Comment: sry replace it with cells.contentView

Answer (score 0):

Collection view cells are re-used: If you scroll them out of sight, the same cell can be returned by `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. The cell will then be in the same state as is was when it was displayed.
Since you add a `subView` to it, this `subView` has thus to be removed in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`, or it may be visible together with the next `subView` that you add.
You could do it, e.g., using

```
[[cells subviews] performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Comment: Then I did probably not understand your problem, but you have to remove previous subViews anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit UICollectionViewCell and add a property of UIImageView. config the imageview for cell.

```
@interface UIImageCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;
@end

@implementation UIImageCollectionViewCell
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self= [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Register class:

```
 [_collectionView registerClass:[UIImageCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"imageCell"];
```

Then return cell like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIImageCollectionViewCell *cell = (UIImageCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"imageCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.imageView.image = [documentImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: now its crashing   -[UICollectionViewCell imageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc8f87792b0
2016-01-27 13:12:11.437 Care Circle[16435:385437] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewCell imageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc8f87792b0'

Comment: Be care of the Identifier `@"imageCell"`.

Comment: @Bangalore It is impossible. Maybe the class which you register is incorrect. Check this `[_collectionView registerClass:[UIImageCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"imageCell"];`